# Настройка кэширования nginx, не кэширует js сформированные через ssi

Tags: nginx, кэширование, ssi, javascript

Есть файл test.inc.js
Его содержимое:

```
<!--#include file="js/test1.js"-->
<!--#include file="js/test2.js"-->
```

В nginx пишу:

```
location ~test.inc.(js)$ {
     try_files $uri @proxy_backend;
     ssi_types application/x-javascript;
     expires 7d;
     gzip on;
     root   /home/www;
        }
```

В браузере при 2 обновлениях все равно получаю "200 OK" по этому файлу.
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_last_modified